# Which version of the Windows SDK uses xinput1_3.dll?

Tags: c++, dll, xna, winapi, xinput

I currently have Windows SDK 7.0A installed. This version of the SDK contains `Xinput.h` which references `xinput9_1_0.dll`:

```
#define XINPUT_DLL_A  "xinput9_1_0.dll"
```

I need my program to use `xinput1_3.dll` instead. I figured that in order to do this, I must link with the `xinput.lib` file from an earlier version of Windows SDK.

But, which version of the SDK contains the `Xinput.h` file that references `xinput1_3.dll`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution is actually to use the Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010) by modifying the include and library dirs for your project. The `XInput.h` file from the DirectX SDK...

```
// XInput.h from the DirectX SDK

#ifndef XINPUT_USE_9_1_0
#define XINPUT_DLL_A  "xinput1_3.dll"
#define XINPUT_DLL_W L"xinput1_3.dll"
#else
#define XINPUT_DLL_A  "xinput9_1_0.dll"
#define XINPUT_DLL_W L"xinput9_1_0.dll"
#endif
#ifdef UNICODE
    #define XINPUT_DLL XINPUT_DLL_W
#else
    #define XINPUT_DLL XINPUT_DLL_A
#endif
```

... is actually a little different to the one from the Windows SDK...

```
// XInput.h from the Windows SDK

#define XINPUT_DLL_A  "xinput9_1_0.dll"
#define XINPUT_DLL_W L"xinput9_1_0.dll"
#ifdef UNICODE
    #define XINPUT_DLL XINPUT_DLL_W
#else
    #define XINPUT_DLL XINPUT_DLL_A
#endif
```

So, by default, the DirectX SDK will actually use `xinput1_3.dll`.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange... I wonder why this was down voted. Seemed like the best solution to me. Can any one shed some light on this?

Comment: Seems like a good answer. Loosely related: what are the differences between 1.3 and older versions of XInput? I have found a MSDN document, but it is very brief and does not really say much: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh405051(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The modified date on `XInput9_1_0.dll` reads 2009-07-14, so I will try to use the latest version before this release, which is: [v6.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=F26B1AA4-741A-433A-9BE5-FA919850BDBF&displaylang=en) (Windows Server 2008 & .NET 3.5 SDK) from 2008-02-05